# How may one iterate over a SpatRaster's cell values?

Tags: r, for-loop, geospatial, raster, terra

I am coming from a Python background, but have been working with R's terra package lately in order to better deal with geospatial raster data.

I have been wanting to create a for loop that allows one to iterate over a SpatRaster's cells' values, in order to populate another SpatRaster of the same size, resolution and coord. ref. depending on some conditions.

My goal is to create a loop similar to the one below; this would work for a Python list-of-lists, and I am used to data frames having this structure in Python, but I have been unable to create something equivalent in R:

```
for row in raster_1:
 for column in row:
  if value_1 <= [row, column] < value_2:
   raster_2[row, column] = 5
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Edit: I have been able to create a loop similar to the one below, however, I am not sure whether this could be the most efficient solution when dealing with rasters with over 1 000 000 cells each and 24 different "if".

```
# Load required libraries
library(terra)

# define rast_1 where values in each row are constant 
repeated_values_1 <- rep(71:75, each = 5)
m_1 <- matrix(repeated_values_1, nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
rast_1 <- rast(m_1) |> `names<-`("raster_1")

# define rast_2 where values in each column are constant 
repeated_values_2 <- rep(1:5, each = 5)
m_2 <- matrix(repeated_values_2, ncol = 5)
rast_2 <- rast(m_2) |> `names<-`("raster_2")

# define rast_3 which has the same resolution and extent as rast_1 and rast_2
rast_3 <- rast(rast_1, names = "raster_3", vals = NA)

# iterate over every cell of both rast_1 and rast_2
for (row in 1:nrow(rast_1)) {
  for (col in 1:ncol(rast_1)) {
    value_1 <- (rast_1)[row, col]
    value_2 <- (rast_2)[row, col]
    
    # check whether the values of rast_1 and rast_2 in the same position
    # satisfy certain conditional statements
    if (1 <= value_2 && value_2 < 3 && 70 <= value_1 && value_1 < 73) {
      rast_3[row, col] <- 0.1
    } else if (3 <= value_2 && value_1 >= 75){
      rast_3[row, col] <- 0.2
    }
  }
}

# plotting for comparison
layout(matrix(1:3, nrow = 1, ncol = 3))
plot(rast_1, main="rast_1")
plot(rast_2, main="rast_2")
plot(rast_3, main="rast_3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally avoid looping through raster cells as much as possible and use subsetting, raster algbera, `terra::ifel()` and other `{terra}` methods - https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/terra-package.html .

It's not just some 1 .. 5% performance gain, even for tiny rasters looping through every single cell, applying some logic and reading/writing a single cell value at a time can easily be 1000+ times slower compared to more suitable methods.

E.g. consider something like this to move over only specific values and to set a range to a fixed value:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.39
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

# input matrix 
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
m
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [2,]    6    7    8    9   10
#> [3,]   11   12   13   14   15
#> [4,]   16   17   18   19   20
#> [5,]   21   22   23   24   25

# raster 1
rast_1 <- rast(m) |> `names<-`("raster_1")
rast_1
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 5, 5, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 5, 0, 5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        : raster_1 
#> min value   :        1 
#> max value   :       25
plot(rast_1, main = "rast_1")

# raster 2, filled with NA values
rast_2 <- rast(rast_1, names = "raster_2", vals = NA)

# creating masks (TRUE / FALSE values):
(rast_1 %% 2 == 0) |> plot(main = "rast_1 %% 2 == 0")
(rast_1 > 10 & rast_1 <= 15) |> plot(main = "rast_1 > 10 & rast_1 <= 15")

## using those for submitting
# copy certain values from one raster to another:
rast_2[rast_1 %% 2 == 0] <- rast_1[rast_1 %% 2 == 0]

# set certain target values based on source values:
rast_2[rast_1 > 10 & rast_1 <= 15] <- 25
plot(rast_2, main = "rast_2[...] <- ...")
```

[image]

If you absolutely do need to loop through cells, this should get you started:

```r
rast_3 <- rast(rast_1, names = "raster_3", vals = NA)
for (cid in 1:ncell(rast_1)){
  if(rast_1[cid] > 10 && rast_1[cid] <= 15){
    rast_3[cid] <- 5
  }
}
```

###### `bench::mark()` subset vs loop with a simple condition vs `ifel()`

Though here's a simple benchmark with a tiny 100x100 raster just to illustrate what you should be prepared for, results from all three methods are comparable ( `identical(rast_x[], rast_y[])` is `TRUE` ).

```r
# 100x100 input rater for benchmark, 
# random values in range of 1..10, uniform distribution, 
# each value is used for ~10% of cells
set.seed(123)
rast_uniform <- 
  sample(1:10, size = 10000, replace = TRUE) |> 
  matrix(nrow = 100) |>
  rast()
rast_uniform
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 100, 100, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 100, 0, 100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        : lyr.1 
#> min value   :     1 
#> max value   :    10
summary(rast_uniform)
#>      lyr.1       
#>  Min.   : 1.000  
#>  1st Qu.: 3.000  
#>  Median : 6.000  
#>  Mean   : 5.507  
#>  3rd Qu.: 8.000  
#>  Max.   :10.000
table(rast_uniform[])
#> 
#>    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
#> 1034 1003 1021  941  987  966  980 1028 1009 1031

# NA rasters for benchmark
rast_na_1 <- rast_na_2 <- rast_na_3 <- rast(rast_uniform, vals = NA)

# banchmark sets ~10% of cell values, subset vs loop vs ifel()
bnch <- bench::mark(
  subset = { rast_na_1[rast_uniform == 5] <- 0; rast_na_1 },
  loop   = { for (cid in 1:ncell(rast_uniform)) {if (rast_uniform[cid] == 5) rast_na_2[cid] <- 0}; rast_na_2 },
  ifel   = { rast_na_3 <- ifel(rast_uniform == 5, 0, NA); rast_na_3 },
  filter_gc = FALSE
)
```

Note the units, milliseconds vs seconds, tested loop is ~1700 times(!) slower when compared against subsetting.

```r
bnch
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 subset       4.68ms   4.85ms  191.        6.26KB     5.97
#> 2 loop         10.26s   10.26s    0.0975    3.23MB     6.34
#> 3 ifel         7.33ms   8.71ms   94.9       8.84KB     5.93
```

###### Edit: applying the same approach on provided example rasters

With provided example where conditions are exclusive, subsetting by boolean SpatRasters still works, though be aware of `1 <= rast_2` vs `rast_2 >= 1`:

```r
## example input rasters
# rast_1, values in each row are constant
as.matrix(rast_1, wide = TRUE) 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   71   71   71   71   71
#> [2,]   72   72   72   72   72
#> [3,]   73   73   73   73   73
#> [4,]   74   74   74   74   74
#> [5,]   75   75   75   75   75
# rast_2, values in each column are constant 
as.matrix(rast_2, wide = TRUE) 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [2,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [3,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5

rast_4 <- rast(rast_1, names = "raster_4", vals = NA)
rast_4[rast_2 >= 1 & rast_2 < 3 & rast_1 >= 70 & rast_1 < 73] <- 0.1
rast_4[rast_2 >= 3 & rast_1 >= 75] <- 0.2
as.matrix(rast_4, wide = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]  0.1  0.1   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]  0.1  0.1   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [5,]   NA   NA  0.2  0.2  0.2

# in somewhat unituitive way, `1 <= rast_2` and `rast_2 >= 1` results are different, 
# definetly something to be aware of:
as.matrix(rast_2 >= 1, wide = TRUE) 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
as.matrix(1 <= rast_2, wide = TRUE) 
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [2,] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [3,] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [4,] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [5,] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

For more complicated scenarios I'd first go through https://rspatial.org/spatial/8-rastermanip.html few times along with https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/terra-package.html ,  there's a good chance that the real world problem is more elegantly solvable through (a combination of) apply-like methods, classification, factor layers, cross-tabulation, ...

Comment: Ouf, I understand how much worse looping is now... However, I cannot think of another way one may consider the individual cell values of 2 rasters and then populate an empty raster accordingly.. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: Why would presented `rast_2[rast_1 > 10 & rast_1 <= 15] <- 25`  (or `raster_2[raster_1 >= value_1 & raster_1 < value_2] <- 5` ) not work for your case? Can you add reproducible example for such case (small input matrix, i.e 5x5, and desired output matrix) to your question?  Boolean subsetting and masking is pretty much the same pattern I'd expect to see in Pyhton code utilizing `rasterio` & `numpy`.

Comment: I think I understand the logic of the mask approach, could you just take a look at the example I have edited in, and tell me if your approach is still the definitive one to follow? Thank you very much for your time and for the insightful reply!

Comment: Added another example that uses values from 2 rasters. If both of those have just 5 levels, in the worst-case scenario you'd have to define 25 masks.  Depending on your actual datasets and actual conditions you'll likely find more elegant methods from `terra` toolset to achieve the same, perhaps more manageable/maintainable, perhaps better performing, but following that presented pattern would still beat anything that involves looping through all cell values.